# wordpress icons disappeared after some css changes

Tags: wordpress, icons, ionicons

My WordPress site is not showing icons properly. there are some digits instead of icons. 
please check the site http://scisocialgrid.org/

This error occurred when I made some changes in skin.min.css. I upload a new file later to solve the problem but still icons can't appear.

Comment: Can you give us a hint and show the code that you changed?

Answer (score 0):

You are no longer loading the font on the website.  I don't show any reference to the font library or cdn anywhere on the site.  Your header should have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
```

Comment: After looking at the css, it appears that the font css might be being referenced more than once.  I see 2 instances of each font symbol, however the one loading first is missing the "\" before the symbol.

"\f243" instead of "f243" in the main-min.css files but you might be able to remove any references in the main-min.css because its already being called correctly in the ionicons cdn referenced initially here.